# Can we have option to get all tenant data in a specific tenant using generic inquiry

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Can we have option to get all tenant data in a Specific tenant using generic inquiry.
I have 3 tenant , each tenant I am using same table that have data tenant specific.
I want to get data from All tenant in a specific tenant using Generic inquiry.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible using a SQL view.  In your SQL view, join your table to the Company table via CompanyID field.  Ex SOOrder.companyID = Company.companyID.   Be sure to return the CompanyID column in your SQL view using an alias, such as 'Tenant'.  Avoid returning the companyID column natively. Finally, create a custom DAC for your SQL view and use a generic inquiry to select the data in your custom DAC.